# Preventing double submissions using PRG pattern

Tags: design, web-applications, mvc

You probably know [PRG (Post/Redirect/Get) pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) used in web applications to avoid double form submission (and usually conseguent item duplication in a data store).

But I keep reading this is not a 100% safe practice to solve the double submission issue:

> The PRG pattern cannot address every scenario of duplicate form submission. For example, if a web user refreshes before the initial submission has completed because of server lag, a duplicate POST request will occur in certain user agents. (*from Wikipedia*)

So, is there a better way to address this problem?

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach is to embed a unique token in the form which gets sent back with the PUT request, and refuse to process a second PUT with the same token.

Of course, nothing prevents the user from loading the form a second time, filling it with identical data, and submitting it again, but that wouldn't be a duplicate submission, just s second one.

Answer (score 1):

Post/Redirect/Get is convenient. And yes it would cover most cases of accidental double submission. However, you should not rely on it for idempotent behavior.

Instead, what you want is a Token. The idea is that your form includes a one time use Token generated on the server, which would be send on the request (it is a hidden input field on the form). Sending the form multiple times would result in sending the same token multiple times, and the server would be able to know it is the same request (or somebody trying to do request forgery) and only process the first one.

This is the basic idea behind CSRF prevention. Note that this protection is not good enough to prevent CSRF if the site is vulnerable to cross-site scripting. See more at the [Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) from OWASP.

By the way, the PUT and DELETE http methods have idempotent semantics. See [RFC-7231 section 4.2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.2).